# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with iterator (character movement)

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm coding a game so that when you hold D the character moves right and when you hold S the character moves left. The program works just as it should, with one exception. As I'm moving the character (and the character moves perfectly fine), java keeps throwing the error "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException". I did some research and learned that I cannot be adding to the ArrayList "keys" and be iterating it at the same time. With that said, how do I edit the code to still have the character move seamlessly as he is now? This is the only way I know of to make sure the character moves at the same steady pace the second you hold a key down, not take a quick movement, pause, and then continue with the motion.

```
package LevelEditor;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class LevelEditor extends Canvas implements KeyListener, Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

private Object[][] grid = new Object[50][50];

private Graphics bufferGraphics = null; //The graphics for the back buffer
private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = null;

private Thread thread;

private boolean running;

private int selectedBlock = 0;

private int mouseX;
private int mouseY;

private int playerX;
private int playerY;

private ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Iterator itr;

Player player1;

public LevelEditor(Dimension size){
    //Constructor
    this.setPreferredSize(size);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.thread = new Thread(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    running = true;
    mouseX = 0;
    mouseY = 0;
    playerX = 0;
    playerY = 0;
    itr = keys.iterator();


}



public void paint(Graphics g){
    if (bufferStrategy == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
        bufferGraphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        player1 = new Player(playerX, playerY);
        this.thread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //This is what runs when level editor is running
    while (running){
        //Program's logic
        DoLogic();
        Draw();
        DrawBackbufferToScreen();

        Thread.currentThread();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void DoLogic(){

}

public void Draw(){
    //clear secondary screen
    bufferGraphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
    try{
        bufferGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        //this is where everything will be drawn to back buffer
        for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < grid[x].length; y++){
                Object o = grid[x][y];
                if (o instanceof Block){
                    Block blocktoDraw = (Block)o;
                    blocktoDraw.draw(bufferGraphics);
                }
            }
        }

        Block.getBlock(selectedBlock, mouseX, mouseY).draw(bufferGraphics);
        player1.draw(bufferGraphics);

        for (Integer x  : keys){
            if(x == 68 && itr.hasNext()){
                playerX += 5;
                player1.updatePlayer(playerX, playerY);
                player1.draw(bufferGraphics);
                itr.next();
                itr.remove();


            }
            if (x == 65 && itr.hasNext()){
                playerX -= 5;
                player1.updatePlayer(playerX, playerY);
                player1.draw(bufferGraphics);
                itr.next();
                itr.remove();
            }
        }




    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        bufferGraphics.dispose();
    }
}


public void DrawBackbufferToScreen(){
    bufferStrategy.show();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    int mouseX = e.getX();
    int mouseY = e.getY();

    mouseX = (mouseX / 25);
    mouseY = (mouseY / 25);

    if (e.getModifiers() == 16){
        grid[mouseX][mouseY] = Block.getBlock(selectedBlock, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    else if (e.getModifiers() == 4){
        grid[mouseX][mouseY] = Block.getBlock(100, mouseX, mouseY);
    }


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys.clear();

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    keys.add(e.getKeyCode());

}


public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    this.mouseX = e.getX() / 25;
    this.mouseY = e.getY() / 25;

}



@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    int mouseX = e.getX();
    int mouseY = e.getY();

    mouseX = (mouseX / 25);
    mouseY = (mouseY / 25);


    if(e.MOUSE_DRAGGED == 506 && e.getModifiers() == 16){
        grid[mouseX][mouseY] = Block.getBlock(selectedBlock, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    else if (e.MOUSE_DRAGGED == 506 && e.getModifiers() == 4){
        grid[mouseX][mouseY] = Block.getBlock(100, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `Iterator` is the wrong model here: you aren't actually iterating through the list, you are just looking to see if you have an element, and then processing it if you have something.

A better fit is to use a queue - particularly, some sort of concurrent queue, e.g. `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`, since you are modifying it and reading it in different threads.

You can add key codes into this using `queue.add(e.getKeyCode())`, and remove them using `queue.poll()` (or `queue.peek()`), which returns a null value if there is nothing in the queue (akin to `itr.hasNext()` being false).

Comment: Definitely more elegant than my answer. I also noted that iterating seemed to be an odd method in this scenario, but your fix of removing the iterating aspect while keeping the queue of key inputs is quite nice.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never used a BlockingQueue before, but after a little googling I got it working error free. You're the man